# Why are some tags grey and some are light grey?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

I'm here to ask why are some tags grey and some are light grey?
See in this photo:

[image: tags]
[image: discussion]

[image: tags] is light grey, but [image: discussion] is dark grey. Why is that?

---

Edit: it does it here with the tags of *this* question

↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meta sites have compulsory tags, of at least one you need to have.

[image: Screenshot of tag editor]

[bug](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bug) and [discussion](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/discussion) are compulsory. [tags](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tags) is not.

There's a third type of tag called a status tag that only mods and staff can use that's red.

[image: Screenshot showing 3 different tag types and colours, annotated]